# Segmentation Fault on Small(ish) 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation with the following code. Changing the 4000 to 1000 makes the code run fine. I would think that I have enough memory here... How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 4000

void initialize_mx(float mx[][MAXLEN])
{
  int i, j;
  float c=0;
  for(i=0;i<MAXLEN;i++){
  for(j=0;j<MAXLEN;j++) mx[i][j]=c;
  }
}
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i, j;
  float confmx[MAXLEN][MAXLEN];
  initialize_mx(confmx);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @berry: You can't initialize an array type with malloc, only pointer types.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp sorry, you're bang on of course. Shows how rusty my C is (and why I shouldn't post ad-hoc comments when tired!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're overflowing the stack.

When you call `initialize_mx()` it allocates stack space for it's local variables (confmx in your case). This space, which is limited by your OS (check ulimit if you're on linux), can get overflowed if local variables are too big.

Basically you can:

1. Declare confmx as a global variable as cnicutar suggests.
2. [Allocate memory space for your array dynamically.](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch9x.htm) and pass a pointer to `initialize_mx()`

EDIT: Just realized you must still allocate memory space if you pass a pointer so you have those two options :)

Comment: Considering that this site is called StackOverflow, a very suiting question. <g>

Comment: That was my first question here at SO and i used the tutorial I'm linking to as a guide to understand my problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using 4000*4000*4 bytes on your stack, if I didn't make any calculation errors, that's 61MB, which is a lot. It works with 1000 because in that case you are only using nearly 4MB on your stack.

Answer (score 1):

`4000*4000*sizeof(float)==64000000`. I suspect your operating system may have a limit on the stack size between 4 and 64 MB.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted smallish isn't small for `auto` class variables which are allocated on the stack.

Depending on your needs, you could

```
static float confmx[MAXLEN][MAXLEN];
```

which would allocate the storage in the BSS. You might want to consider a different storage system as one often only needs a sparse matrix and there are more efficient ways to store and access matrices where many of the cells are zero.